# celery does not start on centos 5.4

Tags: python, celery

I install celery using "pip install celery" and setup the celeryconfig.py to talk to the rabbitmq server running on another server running in the same network.
The python version i have is 2.7
When i try to run start celeryd i get the following error:

```
# celeryd -l info -I tasks
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/bin/celeryd", line 9, in  <module>
load_entry_point('celery==2.1.4', 'console_scripts', 'celeryd')()
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 166, in main
worker.execute_from_commandline()
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 40, in execute_from_commandline
return self.run(*args, **vars(options))
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 83, in run
from celery.apps.worker import Worker
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 15, in <module>
from celery.task import discard_all
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from celery.task.builtins import PingTask, ExecuteRemoteTask
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/builtins.py", line 18, in <module>
schedule=crontab(minute="00", hour="04", day_of_week="*"))
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 236, in __init__
self.hour = self._expand_cronspec(hour, 24)
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 211, in _expand_cronspec
result = crontab_parser(max_).parse(cronspec)
File "/opt/race/share/sw/os/Linux_2.6_libc2.5_i686/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 144, in parse
return self.parser.parseString(cronspec).pop()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the latest version of `pyparsing`

You can do so by doing:

```
pip install -U pyparsing
```

Comment: I didn't know celery uses pyparsing!

Comment: @Paul, we do actually! it's used for parsing crontab expressions: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/schedules.py#L55-144